# Sorting LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>.entrySet() by the keys, but in the middle of the keys using a regex

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, dictionary

I have a LinkedHashMap which maps strings to string arrays.

The keys have the format of something like this: "`xxx (yyy(0.123))`"

Basically, I want to be able to sort the entry set in such a way that it sorts it by the decimal part, and not the beginning of the string. What I have done so far is converting the entry set to an ArrayList so that I can try calling Arrays.sort on it, but obviously that's going to just sort by the beginning of the string.

What I'm currently thinking is that I would have to go through this array, convert each key in the pair to a custom class with a comparator that compares the way I want it to (with the regular expression `.*\((.*)\)\)` to find the decimal). However, that sounds like a bunch of unnecessary overhead, so I was wondering if there was a simpler way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you cannot "sort" a `LinkedHashMap`.  `LinkedHashMap` maintain the iteration order based on the order of insertion.

If you means creating another `LinkedHashMap` by inserting using values from the original map, with order based on sorted order: You need to be aware of any new entries added after your initial construction will be unsorted.  So you may want to create an unmodifiable Map.

For the `Comparator` implementation, you do not need to make it to your custom class. Just create a comparator that do the comparison is good enough.

Like this:

(haven't compiled, just to show you the idea)

```
// assume the key is in format of "ABCDE,12345", and you want to sort by the numeric part:
Map<String, Foo> oldMap = ....; // assume you populated something in it
Map<String, Foo> sortedMap 
    = new TreeMap((a,b) -> {
                     // here I use split(), you can use regex
                     int aNum = Integer.valueOf(a.split(",")[1]);
                     int bNum = Integer.valueOf(b.split(",")[1]);
                     if (aNum != bNum )  {
                         return aNum - bNum;
                     } else {
                         return a.compareTo(b);
                     });
sortedMap.addAll(oldMap);
// now sortedMap contains your entries in sorted order.
// you may construct a new LinkedHashMap with it or do whatever you want
```

Comment: Hey, that works, but the regex isn't matching it for some reason. I'll just try to debug it. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I fixed the problem with the regex (didn't call Matcher.find(), duh), but now I'm having a problem with it calling the comparator for no reason (before it tacks on the `(yyy(0.123))` part), and it's breaking the tree map. EDIT: turns out there's a containsKey function that's calling the comparator for some reason EDIT 2: I removed that thing, now It's only putting one thing into the map, and I'm really not sure why...

Comment: Raise another question as it is a separate problem.  `TreeMap` use `Comparator` or `Comparable.compareTo` for checking ordering and equal-ness.  Nothing we can comment on without seeing your `Comparator` implementation

Comment: Okay it turns out it was because I was casting the return result to an int (wasn't working without it), so it was truncating the double values to 0, making them all equal each other, and thus not inserting anything past the first item. Thanks!

Comment: it seems a code smell to me. If you have two different keys but with same numeric part, I think you should still treat it as different.  Comparing the String as last resort should avoid similar problem.  And, your idea of creating custom class for key may be something you should considerate if there is huge amount of data, or if you need to update the map frequently. And with a custom class as Key, you don't need a comparator, just create a `TreeMap<CustomKey, Foo>`, nad have `CustomKey` implements `Comparable`

Comment: Your solution works fine after fixing that bug (I multiplied all the doubles by 1000 and then casted to int). I just really didn't feel like refactoring all of my code for my idea to work, though. It seems to be working as fast as it did before.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution sounds fine.

If you run into performance issues, you could look buffering the decimal value by replacing your strings with an object that contains the string and the decimal value. Then it does not need to be recalculated multiple times during the sort.

There are trade offs for the buffered solution as above and figuring out which technique is optimal will really depend on your entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to use `LinkedHashMap`?  The javadoc specifically states

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order)

`TreeMap` seems a better fit for what you're trying to achieve, which allows you to provide a `Comparator` at construction.  Using Java 8, this could be achieved with something like:

```
private static final String DOUBLE_REGEX = "(?<value>\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)";
private static final String FIND_REGEX = "[^\\d]*\\(" + DOUBLE_REGEX + "\\)[^\\d]*";
private static final Pattern FIND_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(FIND_REGEX);

private static final Comparator<String> COMPARATOR = Comparator.comparingDouble(
    s -> {
        final Matcher matcher = FIND_PATTERN.matcher(s);
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot compare key: " + s);
        }
        return Double.parseDouble(matcher.group("value"));
    });

private final Map<String, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<>(COMPARATOR);
```

---

Edit: If it has to be a `LinkedHashMap` (`yours`), you can always:

```
map.putAll(yours);
yours.clear();
yours.putAll(map);
```

Comment: Maybe make the lambda body a method so you can write a unit test.

Comment: Fair point, but the lambda body is just becoming the `compare` method for the `COMPARATOR`, so you could always just unit test that the `COMPARATOR` is doing its job correctly.

Comment: It was a LinkedHashMap because I did care about the insertion order previously, but now I need it to be ordered this way. TreeMap should be find to use, however. Thanks though, I'll try that.

Comment: New problem: I tried changing the LinkedHashMap directly to a TreeMap using the comparator that you provided, but it doesn't seem to be putting in some key-value pairs that it had without the comparator. Any idea why?

Comment: Not without seeing some of the code. But this comparator will throw an exception if it can't parse a key, so it could be the reflex is wrong.  If you're using this somewhere performance-sensitive you should probably cache the parse results too so you don't have to keep checking regex matches and double values for things you've already done.

Comment: The problem is that some strings don't actually have the `(yyy(0.123))` part, so I made it so if it doesn't find a match it just returns a 1 (which is bigger than any of the "doubles" that it will find). I don't think performance is an issue. What I'm doing is performing a search which puts stuff into the map. It used to be a LinkedHashMap because I was putting it in as it went through the files, but now I want it to be ordered by the decimal part. Here's a snippet of code from my putInMap method:

Comment: private void putInMap(String filename, String name, String[] ngrams,     TreeMap<String, String[]> resultMap, String matchedNgram) {
        if (!resultMap.containsKey(name)) {
            String[] resultsArray = new String[]{filename
                    .substring(0, filename.length() - LENGTH_OF_EXT)};
            String[] vArray = concat(resultsArray, ngrams);
            if (matchedNgram != null) {
                resultMap.put(name + " (" + matchedNgram + ")", vArray);
            } else {
                resultMap.put(name, vArray);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Sorry about the formatting^ I can't figure out how to fix it.

As for some context, the key is obviously the string that I've been trying to get, the value is a String array, first element of which is the filename associated with it, and rest are tags for the key. It seems to be getting to the .put() part, but it doesn't end up actually putting it in there for whatever reason. It works fine if I do a TreeMap without the Comparator parameter.

Comment: Ah.  `TreeMap` will only insert the latest element if you have two of the doubles equal (it considers the keys as 'equal', and so like any normal `Map`, drops the duplicate for the new value).  You could modify the Comparator to try comparing the double values first, and if they're the same or it fails, compare the `Strings` (note: All of those which satisfied your `returning 1` condition will overwrite one another).

Comment: http://ideone.com/Vo2k3d I had to call the class `Main` due to IdeOne's conventions (and I couldn't use java 8 syntax for bits and pieces).  But that seems to work.

Comment: Is that really the simplest way you can do it? This looks a bit involved...

Comment: I'm trying Adrian's (below) approach, and it seems to be working better but for some reason it's not matching the regex, which I guess I can debug. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Problem in the comparator implementation: if two different keys contains same numeric value, this comparator implementation is treating them as the same key.